# How do I use swipl to open another instantiation of swipl with a file consulted alongwith

Tags: swi-prolog

I tried the following:

```
win_shell(open,swipl,normal).                 % Works but I want a .pl file to be opened.

win_shell(open,'swipl-win myfile.pl',normal). % I want this but it flags an error!

ERROR: Could not execute `swipl-win myfile.pl' (File not found)

ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [8] win_shell(open,'swipl-win myfile.pl',normal)
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

NB: The prolog file is very much there in the current directory.
Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

sbn

Answer (score 0):

win_shell is not equivalent to shell for windows. win_shell uses the browser avec the file reference (not shell command), and applies the browser action specified as first argument. So, the command you used will "open" the file "swipl-win myfile.pl", which does not exist.

This is what you should use instead with the test.pl in the proper folder:

> win_exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/swipl/bin/swipl.exe -c
> c:/users/.../test.pl", show).

win_exec spawns the task (and does its own thread work) and returns true immediately to its own thread. This is what I have in test.pl:

> append([], X, X).
>
> append([X|Xs], Y, [X|Z]) :-   append(Xs, Y, Z).
>
> :- append([a,b],[c,d],X), write(X), get_single_char(Y).

You get a console window showing the result, and wait for you to type in a char to terminate (equivalent of "pause").